# C Program crashes after assigning value to string

Tags: c, malloc

Relatively new to C, don't see what I'm doing wrong here, this piece of code crashes after assigning the 3rd string:

```
QW_Be *sentence = (QW_Be*)malloc(sizeof(QW_Be*));
sentence->questionword->word = words[0];
sentence->verb->word = words[1];
sentence->subject->word = words[2]; //crashes here ?
```

words is an char *[ ], and here's the structure of "sentence":

```
typedef struct QW_Be{
    Word *questionword;
    Word *verb;
    Word *subject;
    Word *rest[];
} QW_Be;
```

and here's the structure of 'Word':

```
typedef struct Word{
    char *word;
    word_type type;
    char *context;
} Word;
```

If you need any more info, just ask !

Comment: `(QW_Be*)malloc(sizeof(QW_Be*));`  -> `(QW_Be*)malloc(sizeof(QW_Be));`.

Comment: might explain what' the difference is ?

Comment: ... and in C : `(QW_Be*)malloc(...` -> `malloc(...`

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: You've left out relevant information.  For example, what type is `words`?   Try providing an [mcve].

Comment: many other issues: `sentence->questionword`: you never allocate memory for this pointer nor for `sentence->verb` nor for `sentence->subject` etc.

Comment: where should I alllocate the memory of those ?

Comment: will someone hit you if you switch to C++? because you should drop C for this kind of thing.

Comment: Well no nobody's going to hit me it's for personal use atm. But I'd liek to learn it the right way in C ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: C is fine for such problems. There is absolutely no need in moving to a different language.

Comment: @TanguyB You have allocated memory for the `sentence` pointer here: `QW_Be *sentence = malloc(sizeof(QW_Be));` Now `sentence->questionword` is also a pointer and you need to allocate memory for it like this: `sentence->questionword = malloc(sizeof(Word))` etc.

Comment: You will probably need to make hard copies of all those members.

Comment: @TanguyB my suggestion: read the chapter about pointers in your C textbook and start with simpler stuff.

Comment: I did read a book, but I guess it's by doing that I learn ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allocate the size of the struct and not the size of a pointer to the struct:

```
QW_Be *sentence = (QW_Be*)malloc(sizeof(QW_Be));
```

Comment: There are further major problems in the code besides the malloc size

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `... = malloc(sizeof *sentence);`

Comment: Well, still not working, but that's due to the issues with not allocating mem to questionword, subject & verb i guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are crashing in an assign value to a string it could be the fact you are assigning a value in a place of the memory who is'nt yours. Besides, make sure to always declare how much memory you want for your string and assign your values in the right place.